# Android Lollipop Patterns.WEB_URL wrong behavior

Tags: android, url, design-patterns, android-5.0-lollipop

I am validating a URL before to open using Patterns.WEB_URL. It works perfect until lollipop that return true to "http://www.google" url for example.

```
final String registrationUrl = "http://www.google";
final Pattern urlPattern =     Patterns.WEB_URL;
Boolean bool = urlPattern.matcher(registrationUrl).matches();
```

Any idea how to validate a URL? URLUtil.isValidUrl() dont work for me.

Comment: It returns true because http:// www.google is valid url. ".google" is registered top-level domain http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/google.html

Comment: @DmitriyStartsev for me, it's returning true for "abc.def". Strange behavior of lollipop. :(

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: @gugarush, Did you find any solution?